# How can I use a generic type with entity framework core?

Tags: c#, generics, ef-core-2.0

If I have a domain model that looks something like this:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Statement { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use it for built in Data Types (string, int, etc...) as well as date.
I want to use it like:

```
var foo = new Foo<string>();
foo.Value = "Hey";
```

how can I persist this to a database using EF Core?

I imagine the database table would look like

```
| Id | Statement | ValueAsString | ValueAsDecimal | ValueAsDate | ValueAsInt | 
| 1  | NULL      | "Hey"         |                |             |            |
| 2  | NULL      |               | 1.1            |             |            |
```

Comment: see my latest comment on my answer. How many columns would you then get...? then make it more abstract, and create some casting-logic to your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should still have a class. Your class `Foo` should be abstract.
So you would get":

```
public abstract class Foo<T> {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Statement { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

then your implementation class would be:

```
public class Orders: Foo<Order> {
}
```

now you have your `Orders` class with your generic type which can be stored.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D Is there an alternative way?  It feels like it defeats the point of generics?

Comment: why does it feel like that? Isn't the whole idea so you wouldn't have to type every letter for every (domain) model for the same things..?  How would your database would look like then? Or your DTO's or other models?

Comment: I'll have to create a class for every type that I want to use Foo with?  If I said I only want to use this for base types does that make it easier?

Comment: `to use with every type`, you say it like it is wrong..? You could aso persist the type (you mean foo?), but then, how would you know what `foo` would be?

Comment: its extra work that I don't need to do in the domain layer.  I don't create a new class for every variation of List<T> that I do.  Could I persist the type T to help?

Comment: @chris31389 currently this is the only way, this is not alternative, and it does not defeat point of Generics, you don't need everything to support generics.

Comment: perhaps we are missing the point, but if you want this generic to safe to db, with no other classes and would be a `simple type`, sure. you could do adjust your property `T Value` to `Object Value` and add a property `Object Type`, where type should contain something like `List` or so, so you could cast it when reading from DB. But... this would definitely not be my choice...

Comment: Doesn't this create one table per subtype?

Comment: This creates one table per subtype since you cannot tell entity framework to create a table for the `Foo` since its a generic class.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to persist different values types to the database in a single table similar to the one in your question, you can do it like this:

```
public interface IHasValue<T> {
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Foo {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Statement { get; set; }
}

public class Foostring : Foo, IHasValue<string> {
    string Value { get; set; }
}

public class FooInt : Foo, IHasValue<int> {
    int Value { get; set; }
}
```

In your `DbContext` class add properties:

```
public DbSet<FooString> FooStrings { get; set: }
public DbSet<FooInt> FooInts { get; set; }
```

You can set the column names for the table in the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext`:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // include the base class so a single table is created for the hierarchy
    // rather than a table for each child class
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable("Foos");

    // Specify the column names or you will get weird names
    modelBuilder.Entity<FooString>().Property(entity => entity.Value)
        .HasColumnName("ValueAsString");
    modelBuilder.Entity<FooInt>().Property(entity => entity.Value)
        .HasColumnName("ValueAsInt");
}
```

This code will generate a table `Foos` with columns `Id`, `Statement`, `Discriminator`, `ValueAsString` and `ValueAsInt`. More info on the `Discrimiator` column can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration)

[image: Image of the resulting table]

You still need to create a class for each Type/column you want to use for `T`, I don't think you can get around that.

Comment: The above code actually creates 2 tables: `Foostring` and `FooInt`. If you force ef to give both tables the same name in the model builder you will get an error. To get this to work you would have to use [table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting).

Comment: I managed to get it working with a single table by including the `Foo` base class in the model (which can be done either by create a `DbSet` for the `Foo` class or by specifying it in the `OnModelCreating` method).

Comment: @somethingRandom did the Foo DbSet have a generic? If so what did you pass into it?

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins No, you create a `DbSet` for the `Foo` class like this `public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set: }`; the `Foo` class is not generic so you don't pass anything to it. Having said that, I found it made more sense to create the `Foos` table manually in the `OnModelCreating` method since you will probably never access that table directly (the `Value` properties are not accessible from that `DbSet`). I have updated the answer will additional info on how to implement this.